# Stop foreach if error occurs

Tags: powershell

The following powershell script will iterate 0 to 10 even exception raised when `$_` is 5. Is it a way to stop the execution when there is an error? I just use `1/0` for illustration.

```
0..10 | % { 
  echo $_ 
  if ($_ -eq 5) { 1/0 } # It will be some complex scripts which may raise error here
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Etan Reisner's solution of setting **$ErrorActionPreference** to **Stop** (`$ErrorActionPreference = 'stop'`) will work. However, if you don't want to want to have to change a global preference variable that affects other code back and forth, **try {} catch {}** will do it. Assuming that you want to know what error stopped the pipeline, you should have the **catch {}** block re-throw the error that was caught, otherwise the pipeline will just stop silently.

Any of the following will work, depending on how granular you want to be about which parts of the code will stop the pipeline of they throw errors:

**1.**

```powershell
0..10 | % {
  echo $_
  if ($_ -eq 5) { 
    try {
      1/0
    } catch {throw $_} 
  }
}
```

**2.**

```powershell
0..10 | % {
  echo $_
  try {
    if ($_ -eq 5) {
      1/0
    }
  } catch {throw $_} 
}
```

**3.**

```powershell
try {
  0..10 | % {
    echo $_
    if ($_ -eq 5) {
      1/0 
    }
  }
} catch {throw $_}
```

Comment: You do realize I explicitly commented that you can set that in as tight a scope as you want, right? You don't need to set it globally. And I also pointed out that many commands accept that setting **as an argument** so the scope is as tight as you can get. This works just fine though.

Comment: As an aside I'm not sure I know **why** this works. Why does catching the original exception and re-throwing it again cause powershell to stop when the original exception didn't cause it to stop?

Answer (score 3):

Set `$ErrorActionPreference` to `Stop` instead of `Continue`.

You can scope this to whatever scope you want.

Many commands take a `-ErrorAction` argument to control this without needing to set the variable (that might apply to what you are really doing but doesn't to for the example).

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping it in `try { ... } catch {}` works, although I'm not sure it's the best way.

Answer (score 0):

```
0..10 | % { 
  echo $_ 
  if ($_ -eq 5) 
  {
    Break
  }
}
```

Comment: You should add a description of how this solves the problem. Include more than a code snippet.

Comment: I don't think that's what he's looking for. He wants to stop the pipeline if the code in the **Foreach-Object** block generates an exception, not if a certain **if** condition is met. I think the reason he used an **if** statement in the example is to better illustrate the issue by having the exception occur halfway through the pipeline. But the idea is not to have the pipeline break if **$_** is equal to 5, but rather if the code contained within the block causes an exception.