# How to get PowerShell error detail from function called from inside a ForEach loop

Tags: powershell

This code works as expected:

```
function Foo ($Dividend) {
    $Divisor = 0
    $Quotient = $Dividend / $Divisor
}

try {
    Foo 1
} catch {
    $Line = $($_.InvocationInfo.Line).Trim()
    $Row = $($_.InvocationInfo.ScriptLineNumber)
    $Col = $($_.InvocationInfo.OffsetInLine)

    Write-Host "Error: $_" -ForegroundColor "Red"
    Write-Host "  -> Row:    $Row" -ForegroundColor "Red"
    Write-Host "  -> Col:    $Col" -ForegroundColor "Red"
    Write-Host "  -> Line:   $Line" -ForegroundColor "Red"
}
```

It prints this text:

```
Error: Attempted to divide by zero.
  -> Row:    3
  -> Col:    5
  -> Line:   $Quotient = $Dividend / $Divisor
```

However this fails:

```
function Foo ($Dividend) {
    $Divisor = 0
    $Quotient = $Dividend / $Divisor
}

try {
    $Dividends = @(1)

    $Dividends | ForEach {
        Foo $_
    }
} catch {
    $Line = $($_.InvocationInfo.Line).Trim()
    $Row = $($_.InvocationInfo.ScriptLineNumber)
    $Col = $($_.InvocationInfo.OffsetInLine)

    Write-Host "Error: $_" -ForegroundColor "Red"
    Write-Host "  -> Row:    $Row" -ForegroundColor "Red"
    Write-Host "  -> Col:    $Col" -ForegroundColor "Red"
    Write-Host "  -> Line:   $Line" -ForegroundColor "Red"
}
```

It prints this:

```
Error: Attempted to divide by zero.
  -> Row:    11
  -> Col:    22
  -> Line:   $Dividends | ForEach {
```

Is there a way to get properly scoped error information when a function is called from within a `ForEach` loop?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need to put the try/catch inside the foreach block like in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29780946/stop-foreach-if-error-occurs/29785821#29785821

Comment: @Eris: That works as well, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The information you're looking for is nested inside the top-level `ErrorRecord` object. You need to unroll the error object to get to the nested information.

Change this:

```
} catch {
    $Line = $($_.InvocationInfo.Line).Trim()
    $Row = $($_.InvocationInfo.ScriptLineNumber)
    $Col = $($_.InvocationInfo.OffsetInLine)

    Write-Host "Error: $_" -ForegroundColor "Red"
    Write-Host "  -> Row:    $Row" -ForegroundColor "Red"
    Write-Host "  -> Col:    $Col" -ForegroundColor "Red"
    Write-Host "  -> Line:   $Line" -ForegroundColor "Red"
}
```

into this:

```
} catch {
    $Line = $($_.Exception.ErrorRecord.InvocationInfo.Line).Trim()
    $Row = $($_.Exception.ErrorRecord.InvocationInfo.ScriptLineNumber)
    $Col = $($_.Exception.ErrorRecord.InvocationInfo.OffsetInLine)

    Write-Host "Error: $_" -ForegroundColor "Red"
    Write-Host "  -> Row:    $Row" -ForegroundColor "Red"
    Write-Host "  -> Col:    $Col" -ForegroundColor "Red"
    Write-Host "  -> Line:   $Line" -ForegroundColor "Red"
}
```

and the code should behave as you expect.